# Handsontable delete multiple rows

Tags: jquery, handsontable

I am new to Handsontable. I am trying to delete multiple selected table rows using '**getSelected**' and '**alter**' methods (remove_row). However, with my code below I am getting the error "selection" not defined in Firebug and "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined " in Chrome. It doesn't matter which row I select or how many. I still get the error and no rows are deleted. What am I doing wrong please?

```
    $(document).ready(function () {

    var myData = [
        ["", "Kia", "Nissan", "Toyota", "Honda"],
        ["2008", 10, 11, 12, 13],
        ["2009", 20, 11, 14, 13],
        ["2010", 30, 15, 12, 13]
    ];

    $("#exampleGrid").handsontable({
        data: myData,
        startRows: 5,
        startCols: 5,
        //minSpareCols: 1, //always keep at least 1 spare row at the right
        //minSpareRows: 1, //always keep at least 1 spare row at the bottom,
        rowHeaders: true,
        colHeaders: true,
        contextMenu: true,
        currentRowClassName: 'currentRow',
        currentColClassName: 'currentCol'

    });

    $edit = $('#exampleGrid');

    function editRows() {

        $('#addtop').on('click', function () {
            $edit.handsontable('alter', 'insert_row', 0);
        });

        $('#addbottom').on('click', function () {
            $edit.handsontable('alter', 'insert_row');
        });

        var selection = $edit.handsontable('getSelected');
        $('.deletebutton').on('click', function () {
            $edit.handsontable('alter', 'remove_row', selection[0], selection[2]);
        });

    }

    editRows();
  });
```

Here is my fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/EfhqJ/48/.

Thanks.

Comment: Solved. I needed to move getSelected inside the on handler:          $('.deletebutton').on('click', function () {
            var selection = $edit.handsontable('getSelected');
            if (selection) {
                $edit.handsontable('alter', 'remove_row', selection[0], selection[2]);
            }
        });

Answer (score 1):

your "selection" variable is not visible within the scope of the onClick handler.

Try moving "var selection = ..." into the handler function.
Something like...

```
    $('.deletebutton').on('click', function () {
        var selection = $edit.handsontable('getSelected');
        $edit.handsontable('alter', 'remove_row', selection[0], selection[2]);
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

As it currently stands, `getSelected()` returns nothing...

```
getSelected: function () { 
     //https://github.com/warpech/jquery-handsontable/issues/44 
     //cjl if (selection.isSelected()) { 
     //return [priv.selStart.row(), priv.selStart.col(), priv.selEnd.row(), priv.selEnd.col()]; 
     //} 
     }
```

which is a huge problem since *handsontable* references that function quite a bit.  However, we can fortunately use the [afterSelectionEnd event](https://github.com/warpech/jquery-handsontable/wiki/Events).

> `afterSelectionEnd (r: Number, c: Number, r2: Number, c2: Number)`
>   Callback fired after one or more cells are selected (on mouse up). 
>   
> Parameters:
>   `r` selection start row
>   `c` selection start column
>   `r2` selection end row
>   `c2` selection end column

According to the [API](https://github.com/warpech/jquery-handsontable/wiki),

> `alter ('remove_row', index: Number, amount: Number (Optional), source: String (Optional))`
>   Remove the row(s) at given index. Default amount equals 1

This means in order to use `alter('remove_row')`, we only need to provide the index.

---

Here is a [working demo](http://jsfiddle.net/dirtyd77/9z3qj/4/) I made to get the desired result.

**NOTE:**

Due to a [bug](https://github.com/warpech/jquery-handsontable/issues/44), we need to add some logic in the `afterSelectionEnd event`.

JAVASCRIPT:

```
var myData = [
    ["", "Kia", "Nissan", "Toyota", "Honda"],
    ["2008", 10, 11, 12, 13],
    ["2009", 20, 11, 14, 13],
    ["2010", 30, 15, 12, 13]
    ];

//declare row vars
var row1 = null,
    row2 = null;

var $container = $("#exampleGrid");

$container.handsontable({
    data: myData,
    startRows: 5,
    startCols: 5,
    minSpareCols: 0,
    minSpareRows: 0,
    rowHeaders: true,
    colHeaders: true,
    contextMenu: true,
    afterSelectionEnd: function(x1, y1, x2, y2){

        //add this because of bug
          if( (x1 <= x2 && y1 < y2) || (x1 < x2 && y1 <= y2) || (x1 == x2 && y1 == y2)) {
            row1 = x1;
            if(x1 == 0)
                row2 = parseInt(x2 + 1);
              else
                row2 = x2;
        }
        else if( (x1 >= x2 && y1 > y2) || (x1 > x2 && y1 >= y2)) {
            row1 = x2;
            if(x2 == 0)
                row2 = parseInt(x1 + 1);
              else
                row2 = x1;
        }
        else if(x1 < x2 && y1 > y2) {
            row1 = x1;
            row2 = x2;
        }
        else if(x1 > x2 && y1 < y2) {
            row1 = x2;
            row2 = x1;
        }
    }
});

//gets instance of handsontable
    var instance = $container.handsontable('getInstance');

$('#delete').click(function(){
    if(row1 != null){
        if(row2 != null || row2 != row1 ){
            instance.alter('remove_row', row1, row2);
        }
        else{
            instance.alter('remove_row', row1);
        }
        row1 = null;
        row2 = null;
    }else{
        alert('Please select a cell...');   
    }
});
```

Hope this helps and let me know if you need anything else!

Answer (score 0):

you just need to add `outsideClickDeselects: false` to your options of constructor, then you will get the correct result of getSelected().

and here is the live demo http://jsfiddle.net/czz82kL5/2/