# Not able to delete rows using HandsOnTable

Tags: jquery, handsontable

I am not able to remove rows with the latest version. I am using version `0.9.9`.

This is what I do:

```
var $container = $("#add-table");
$container.handsontable(options);

var handsontable = $container.data('handsontable');
var data = handsontable.getData();
if(data.length > 1 && handsontable.isEmptyRow(data.length-1)) {
    handsontable.alter('remove_row', parseInt(data.length-1));
}
```

There was a similar question on [Handsontable delete multiple rows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17092896/handsontable-delete-multiple-rows/17473644) but that does not solve my purpose. The fiddle on this link does not work with the solution provided.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Can you give an example of what your table contains?

Comment: Its an empty table with no data

Comment: Then you're not actually removing any rows. Set the `minSpareRows: 0` and `minSpareCols: 0` in the handsontable options if you don't want the extra rows and columns displayed.

Comment: Check out this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5xCqN/1/). You can change those options to see the effect.

Comment: What I am trying to do is, I have set the `minsSpareRows` to 1 and while I fill in data, the rows are added. Now, before submitting the table, I don't want any errors. So, I try to remove the last row and validate the form. Since, the last row is empty, I will always get validation errors. And I am not able to remove the last row because of this issue.

Comment: Check this fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/rizwaniqbal/v967j/1/

Comment: See if http://jsfiddle.net/v967j/2/ works for you. I couldn't get the `getSelected` function to work so that might be a bug with the library.

Comment: @rizwaniqbal please provide the options you have used. Tq

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As it currently stands, `getSelected()` returns nothing...

```
getSelected: function () { 
     //https://github.com/warpech/jquery-handsontable/issues/44 
     //cjl if (selection.isSelected()) { 
     //return [priv.selStart.row(), priv.selStart.col(), priv.selEnd.row(), priv.selEnd.col()]; 
     //} 
     }
```

which is a huge problem since *handsontable* references that function quite a bit.  However, we can fortunately use the [afterSelectionEnd event](https://github.com/warpech/jquery-handsontable/wiki/Events).

> `afterSelectionEnd (r: Number, c: Number, r2: Number, c2: Number)`
>   Callback fired after one or more cells are selected (on mouse up). 
>   
> Parameters:
>   `r` selection start row
>   `c` selection start column
>   `r2` selection end row
>   `c2` selection end column

According to the [API](https://github.com/warpech/jquery-handsontable/wiki),

> `alter ('remove_row', index: Number, amount: Number (Optional), source: String (Optional))`
>   Remove the row(s) at given index. Default amount equals 1

This means in order to use `alter('remove_row')`, we only need to provide the index.

---

Here is a [working demo](http://jsfiddle.net/dirtyd77/9z3qj/4/) I made to get the desired result.

**NOTE:**

Due to a [bug](https://github.com/warpech/jquery-handsontable/issues/44), we need to add some logic in the `afterSelectionEnd event`.

JAVASCRIPT:

```
var myData = [
    ["", "Kia", "Nissan", "Toyota", "Honda"],
    ["2008", 10, 11, 12, 13],
    ["2009", 20, 11, 14, 13],
    ["2010", 30, 15, 12, 13]
    ];

//declare row vars
var row1 = null,
    row2 = null;

var $container = $("#exampleGrid");

$container.handsontable({
    data: myData,
    startRows: 5,
    startCols: 5,
    minSpareCols: 0,
    minSpareRows: 0,
    rowHeaders: true,
    colHeaders: true,
    contextMenu: true,
    afterSelectionEnd: function(x1, y1, x2, y2){

        //add this because of bug
          if( (x1 <= x2 && y1 < y2) || (x1 < x2 && y1 <= y2) || (x1 == x2 && y1 == y2)) {
            row1 = x1;
            if(x1 == 0)
                row2 = parseInt(x2 + 1);
              else
                row2 = x2;
        }
        else if( (x1 >= x2 && y1 > y2) || (x1 > x2 && y1 >= y2)) {
            row1 = x2;
            if(x2 == 0)
                row2 = parseInt(x1 + 1);
              else
                row2 = x1;
        }
        else if(x1 < x2 && y1 > y2) {
            row1 = x1;
            row2 = x2;
        }
        else if(x1 > x2 && y1 < y2) {
            row1 = x2;
            row2 = x1;
        }
    }
});

//gets instance of handsontable
    var instance = $container.handsontable('getInstance');

$('#delete').click(function(){
    if(row1 != null){
        if(row2 != null || row2 != row1 ){
            instance.alter('remove_row', row1, row2);
        }
        else{
            instance.alter('remove_row', row1);
        }
        row1 = null;
        row2 = null;
    }else{
        alert('Please select a cell...');   
    }
});
```

Hope this helps and let me know if you need anything else!

Answer (score 1):

So i am guessing you want to delete an empty last row ?

Make sure you have not set minSpareRows to a value more than 0(default) . If the minSpareRows is more than zero u cannot delete the extra row using alter('remove_row').

i used this data to simulate the empty last row :

```
var myData = [
    ["", "Kia", "Nissan", "Toyota", "Honda"],
    ["2008", 10, 11, 12, 13],
    ["2009", 20, 11, 14, 13],
    ["2010", 30, 15, 12, 13],
    ["",,,]
];
```

Checkout the example .When u click on del link it deletes the empty last row . Hope this helps you

[Working Example](http://jsfiddle.net/6yUVb/)